# Browserify giving ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, browserify, require

I am trying browserify for first time with my express app. I have installed browserify globally. I am getting the error mentioned in subject. I have looked this over several times and all looks correct. I'm thinking maybe something w/browserify and express. My setup is

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

I used this command to install browserify

```
browserify public/javascripts/main.js -o public/javascripts/bundle.js
```

My directory structure is

```
root
    ---public
       ---javascripts
           bundle.js
           main.js
```

and my ejs

```
    <script src="javascripts/bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/main.js"></script>
```

which are 200 ok.
And my main.js contains line

```
let helper_functions = require('./library/helper_functions');
```

Is there something I've missed. All docs point to this is how you do it. Any guidance much appreciated.

Update: I just want clarify if Im exported several functions in helper_function.js it can be done like:

```
let helper_functions =  
function strToNumberArray(str, separator = ',') {
    // function stuff
}

    // Function to convert string to an array then convert each element to a number              
 // ========================================================================================== //
    function strToNumberArray(str, separator = ',') {
       function stuff//
    }
module.export = helperFunctions;
```

Comment: Why are you including your source file? You need to include only your bundle file

Comment: main.js still has functionality needed for app. I just took out some helper functions to try out browserify and make main.js more manageable.

Comment: But that is already present in bundle.js too when you pass main.js to browserify all it does is include the implementation of require and load the appropriate modules that you have defined and included. So why you need to include the same file twice?

Comment: Yes now that you mention it Looking deeper into bundle.js I see all of main.js. All Examples I've read showed putting both files in index.js. Are you saying I dont need main.js in index.js?

Comment: Yes you don't need to include that in your index html. All you need is the bundled file. If you want to expose one or all of your methods to the window's object. You can always configure browserify to do that or a cheap trick is add the module directly to window object before using module.exports

Comment: " If you want to expose one or all of your methods to the window's object." I'm sorry you lost me there. Can you be more specific.Do I have to change how I call my helper functions now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164214/discussion-between-karthick-and-alan).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Sorry that was awhile ago, Normally that error is caused because a js file with a require statement in it is being run in the browser environment. I had that going on. Main.js was not needed because browserify would include that module dependency when it built bundle.js. The only script I needed to include in the index.html was bundle.js.